# How to enable receiving Facebook Bot incoming messages from people(general public) not in Developer's List?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, webhooks, facebook-webhooks

I am developing a Facebook Messenger bot using the Facebook official API. But the problem is I do receive messages I sent by my account to this page on Bot but can't receive it from other people? I am the developer of this ChatBot.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/submission-process

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try coding the FB API to enable msgs from Facebook itself and try and see what programs have access to what you need.(enable it if not granted) worst case scenario use a 3rd party program to see what console elements they use to link there features to show your notifications like {eg. a notification program}< then code it to how the program does it. If this sounds like gibrish you can message me via www.djkailash@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks for the answer Brother, I think I was missing this permission 'pages_messaging' now I have made a submission on it I will message you on how it goes thanks

Comment: Thank you, now it is able to receive it so it was that missing permision.

Comment: Not a problem M Jane.